# Debugging JAR library in Android application

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, jar

I have a project (set of Java classes) which I build using Maven as a JAR file, then I add the JAR in my Android application (using Android Studio), adding `compile files('***.jar')` in my build.gradle.

At the moment it works fine, but while debugging the app, when execution enters into the JAR Android Studio's, the debugger shows me decompiled sources (which are different from my original sources), not the original sources. How can I do to debug the JAR using the JAR's original sources?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the breakpoints for the library classes.

Still if you want to check the source code of the jar files you can use https://sourceforge.net/projects/dex2jar/ tool to review the source code functionality of the library code.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this option in proguard file -

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile 
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

also make `minifyEnabled false`

This will make easier debugging. Look at this - https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#stacktrace